# Navigating (Routing) from one page to another in different folders in jsx Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, redirect, jsx

I'm trying to when a user enters a correct email and password it redirects him to the main page (blog.jsx) which is located in mainPage folder.

When I run my code it doesn't display any errors in the console but it doesn't redirect it when you enter the correct email and password (the if-else statement works because when users enters wrong email and password the popup screen shows up)

Here is my code:

```
  const login =() =>{
    Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/login',{
      email:email,
      password:password
    }).then((response)=>{
      if(response.data.message){
        alert(response.data.message)
      }
      else{
        return <Redirect to="../mainPage/blog" />
      }
    })
  }
```

Full code:

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import {useState} from "react";
import {useHistory} from "react-router-dom";
import Axios from 'axios';
import {
  BoldLink,
  BoxContainer,
  FormContainer,
  Input,
  MutedLink,
  SubmitButton,
} from "./common";
import { Marginer } from "../marginer";
import { AccountContext } from "./accountContext";

export function LoginForm(props) {
  let history = useHistory();
  const { switchToSignup } = useContext(AccountContext);
  const [email, setEmail]=useState('');
  const [password, setPassword]=useState('');
  
  
  const login =() =>{
    Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/login',{
      email:email,
      password:password
    }).then((response)=>{
      if(response.data.message){
        alert(response.data.message)
      }
      else{
        history.push("../mainPage/blog");
      }
    })
  }

  const myFunction =()=>{
    alert("TODO");
  }
  
  return (
    <BoxContainer>
      <FormContainer>
        <Input type="email" placeholder="Email" onChange={(e)=>{setEmail(e.target.value)}}/>
        <Input type="password" placeholder="Password" onChange={(e)=>{setPassword(e.target.value)}}/>
      </FormContainer>
      <Marginer direction="vertical" margin="1em" />
      <MutedLink href="#" onClick={myFunction}>Forget your password?</MutedLink>
      <Marginer direction="vertical" margin="1em" />
      <SubmitButton type="submit" onClick={login} >Login</SubmitButton>
      <Marginer direction="vertical" margin="1em" />
      <MutedLink href="#" onClick={switchToSignup}>
        Don't have an accoun?{" "}
        <BoldLink href="#" onClick={switchToSignup}>
          Register
        </BoldLink>
      </MutedLink>
    </BoxContainer>
  );
}
```

I tried using Redirect and Link but it didn't work for either.
Any hint/tip would be great. Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 1):

Returning a React element (`<Redirect.../>`) from a callback won't do anything. Instead, you could use the React Router [`history` object](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/history), like so:

```js
  const history = useHistory();
  const login = () =>{
    Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/login',{
      email:email,
      password:password
    }).then((response)=>{
      if(response.data.message){
        alert(response.data.message)
      }
      else{
        history.push("../mainPage/blog")
      }
    })
  }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the tip, but I'm getting this error message: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'push' of undefined, what should I do

Comment: Did you include the line `const history = useHistory()`? Did you import `useHistory` from react-router?

Comment: yup I did both `import {useHistory} from "react-router-dom";` and `const history = useHistory()˙` in the console it doesn't display error but when you login it displays it

Comment: Are you assigning `history = useHistory()` just before `const login`? Are you defining the `login` function within a component? (That's necessary for `useHistory` to work.)

Comment: yup its before const login

Comment: At this point, I'd need to see more code to understand what's wrong. Can you include the entire component that contains this code?